# Чем трассировка отличается от логирования

Tags: логирование, трассировка

> What is logging and tracing and how they are different?
> Чем трассировка отличается от логирования?

Если принять во внимание, что задающий вопрос - студент с небольшой базой знаний в программировании.

Answer (score 0):

Трассировка и логирование - противоположные по своей сути виды получения информации о поведении приложения.

В моем понимании, различается между ними именно поток данных - в случае логирования это очередь, трассировка же представляет собой стек. Оба подхода имеют право на жизнь, но у каждого свое предназначение:

- Логирование больше подходит для выскоуровневой (с наименьшим погружением в логику приложения), асинхронной информации (event-based)
- Трассировка больше подходит для низкоуровневой (с наибольшим погружением в логику приложения) информации

Как самый элементарный пример можно привести веб-сервис и утилитарный скрипт. В случае веб-сервиса наиболее информативно будет использовать лог (Большое кол-во обращений, можно систематизировать и обрабатывать руками эксплуатации), во втором случае правильнее трейс - для понимания точки отказа и порядка вызовов приведших к определенному состоянию